# File extension for PowerShell 3

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, windows-8

All of us probably know `.bat` for Batch files.

But what is the file extension for **PowerShell 3** scripts?

I found `.ps1` and some other endings but they're only for version 1.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

PowerShell files for all versions are .ps1 (or .psm1, .psd1, etc.).

Comment: Update for 2014: This is still relevant now with Powershell 4. I think the 1 was really just to distinguish it from .ps (PostScript) files, but it made for a lot of confusion!

Comment: always wanted to know what the 1 meant. Guess it's not related to the version but pretty sure the had something to do with it when they created the file type for PS 1.0.

Comment: @Geddon I once read somewhere that they chose `ps1` to avoid conflicts with `ps`, which was already in use by Adobe Photoshop. [Other sources](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/9rZosGOqodE/YEKubAR7f9UJ) say that versioning had been indeed the reason to call it `ps1`, but they dropped this idea when introducing PS 2 ([official source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/11/02/ctp-versioning.aspx)).

Comment: This is a weird extension for sure. Why not .psh then?!

Comment: Just tried it out and it looks like `.psh` is used for HSLS sources in Visual Studio. Given that Microsoft develops VS, it seems likely that they went with `.ps1` also because of that reason.

Comment: ps is a longstanding file extension for postscript files.

Comment: @zolty13 please read the first comment above